# How do I generalize a $m * n$ dimensional megapixel image as a set?

Tags: geometric-topology, intuition

I have been trying to wrap my head around visualizing high-dimensional vector spaces as a state space with many degrees of freedom, and while I feel like I understand it abstractly, I cannot really write it in set-builder notation. Like for a megapixel image, assuming every pixel is stored as an 8-bit color, how can a $m * n$ image be generalized in a set-builder notataion?

Comment: You don't want to think of an image as a set but rather as an element of a set. Here it would be an element of $\mathbb{R}^{3000000}$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "set notation"? There are several different ways to describe sets. i.e. Set builder notation, roster notation, or even just describing the set in words. Also, building on Hans Engler's comment, sets are unordered, so if you were actually trying to describe an image by its set of pixels it wouldn't really work because there is no way to convey order, i.e. what pixel goes where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of your image as a list of $mn$ numbers.  This throws away the rectangular arrangement of the pixels, but that is OK.  If you want a vector space over a finite field, we can imagine that each pixel could take a value from $0$ through $256$ as $257$ is a prime.  This gives us a vector space of dimension $mn$.  You can add two vectors and multiply a vector by a scalar from your field, just as required.  You will satisfy all the necessary commutative, associative, and distributive properties because you are working in a field.